# Problem loading wiki page (javascript generated) in tabview tag

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, tabview

I am a content moderator in [ΒικIkariam](https://ikariam.fandom.com/el)!
I tried to generated a table with a lot of information with javascript.
As a standone page it loads as it should.
But when I try to put it as a tab in an existend page it goes empty!

The javascript code I have created and produces the table is in this [link](https://ikariam.fandom.com/el/wiki/User:Panos78/wikia.js)!.
This code was imported in a Template and this template is imported in this [page](https://ikariam.fandom.com/el/wiki/%CE%91%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B4%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AF%CE%B1/31-32)!.
After this, I have imported the above page as a tab with  in an existed [page](https://ikariam.fandom.com/el/wiki/%CE%91%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B4%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%AF%CE%B1)!.
The tabs are in the middle of the page and the last tab (31-32) shows just what was included in the page without the table that is javascript generated.

I expected that the generated table would appear in the tabbed page but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had asked the same question to the stuff of Fandom and they gave me the solution!

```
mw.hook('wikipage.content').add(function($content)
{
    $content.find('#whatever').html('Hallo');
});
```

So if someone is generating a page with javascript and embed it in another page he should add the above hook in his js file.
Credits to the stuff of Fandom ([Doru](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/User:Dorumin) and [Sophiedp](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/User:Sophiedp)).